# How to get all results, except one row based on a timestamp?

Tags: sql

I have an simple question (?) about SQL. I have come across this problem a few times before and I have always solved it, but I'm looking for a more elegant solution and perhaps a faster solution.

The problem is that I would like to select all rows in a table except the one with the max value in a timestampvalue (in this case this is a summary row but it's not marked as this is any way, and it's not releveant to my result).

I could do something like this:

```
select * from [table] t
where loggedat < (select max(loggedat) from [table] and somecolumn='somevalue')
and somecolumn='somevalue'
```

But when working with large tables this seems kind of slow. Any suggestions?

Comment: SQL-server, Oracle, "access" ? Which database are you using?

Comment: Your solution looks perfectly adequate (and elegant) to me. A join might be faster (or slower).

Comment: Why would you keep a summary row in the raw data table? btw, if you can't change the design, I don't think the query could get much better than what you did.

Comment: Yes I know the solution isn't good, but in this case I can't affect the structure of the database... And code does work, but in real life there is more conditions that just 'somevalue' and the rowcount is quite big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only you don't mind one tiny (4 byte) extra column, then you might possibly go like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY loggedat DESC) AS rownum
  FROM [table] t
  WHERE somecolumn = 'somevalue'
    /* and all the other filters you want */
) s
WHERE rownum > 1
```

In case you do mind the extra column, you'll just have to list the necessary columns explicitly in the outer SELECT.

Comment: Thanks, this one works and it seems to be faster than the other one. At least a little less table scan :-)

Comment: I thought it would, since you don't have to repeat the filters. And one other benefit is that, well, you don't have to repeat the filters. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change your DB structure, then your query (or one with a slight variation using `<>` instead of `<`) is the way to go.

You could add a column `IsSummary bit` to the table, and always mark the most recent row as true (and all others false). Then your query would change to:

```
Select * from [table] where IsSummary = 0 and somecolumn = 'somevalue'
```

This would sacrifice slower speed on inserts (since an insert would also trigger an update of the IsSummary value) in exchange for faster speed on the select query.

Comment: Yep, you hit the spot. The underlaying problem is that the row I want to exclude isn't marked as summary and unfortunately I can't change that...

Comment: Then if you want to do it in one query, there is not much else to be done.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the elegant SQL query you're looking for, but it would be trivial to do it in Java, PHP, etc, after fetching the results. To make it as simple as possible, use ORDER BY timestamp DESC and discard the first row.